# Mimicking Java 8 using VBA (Excel)

Tags: vba, design-patterns

I want to learn about Design Patterns and be able to apply them in Excel VBA. So to learn about patterns I bought a book that seems promising: “Head First Design Patterns”; it presents the material clearly. However, the code exercises/examples are in Java 8. VBA does not have direct counterparts for some things (e.g. “Extends”) so I need to work out how to accomplish the same/similar in VBA.

I am following along with the exercises and doing what I think parallels the Java in VBA. What I am asking here is “am I on the right track?” I know it’s a lot to ask and maybe the question is too broad, but maybe not.

There are some differences in the “Main” procedures because I haven’t completely mimicked the Java in VBA. I am more interested in the “Duck” and “Mallard” implementations.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Here’s the Java for a part of on exercise:

```
    public abstract class Duck {
    FlyBehavior flyBehavior;
    QuackBehavior quackBehavior;

    public Duck() {
    }

    public void setFlyBehavior(FlyBehavior fb) {
        flyBehavior = fb;
    }

    public void setQuackBehavior(QuackBehavior qb) {
        quackBehavior = qb;
    }

    abstract void display();

    public void performFly() {
        flyBehavior.fly();
    }

    public void performQuack() {
        quackBehavior.quack();
    }

    public void swim() {
        System.out.println("All ducks float, even decoys!");
    }

    public class MallardDuck extends Duck {

    public MallardDuck() {

        quackBehavior = new Quack();
        flyBehavior = new FlyWithWings();

    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("I'm a real Mallard duck");
    }
}

    public class MiniDuckSimulator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MallardDuck mallard = new MallardDuck();
        FlyBehavior cantFly = () -> System.out.println("I can't fly");
        QuackBehavior squeak = () -> System.out.println("Squeak");
        RubberDuck  rubberDuckie = new RubberDuck(cantFly, squeak);
        DecoyDuck   decoy = new DecoyDuck();

        Duck     model = new ModelDuck();

        mallard.performQuack();
        rubberDuckie.performQuack();
        decoy.performQuack();

        model.performFly(); 
        model.setFlyBehavior(new FlyRocketPowered());
        model.performFly();
    }
}
```

Here’s what I’ve done in VBA:

```
'@Folder("SimUDuck.Objects.HeadFirst")
Option Explicit
Private Type TObject
    FlyBehavior As IFlyBehavior
    QuackBehavior As IQuackBehavior
    DuckModel As IDuckModel
End Type
Private this As TObject

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    With this
        Set .FlyBehavior = Nothing
        Set .QuackBehavior = Nothing
    End With
End Sub

Public Property Get DuckModel() As IDuckModel
    Set DuckModel = this.DuckModel
End Property
Public Property Set DuckModel(ByVal model As IDuckModel)
    With this
        Set .DuckModel = model
    End With
End Property
Public Property Get FlyBehavior() As IFlyBehavior
    Set FlyBehavior = this.FlyBehavior
End Property
Public Property Set FlyBehavior(ByVal behavior As IFlyBehavior)
    Set this.FlyBehavior = behavior
End Property
Public Property Get QuackBehavior() As IQuackBehavior
    Set QuackBehavior = this.QuackBehavior
End Property
Public Property Set QuackBehavior(ByVal behavior As IQuackBehavior)
    Set this.QuackBehavior = behavior
End Property

Public Sub performFly()
    this.FlyBehavior.Fly
End Sub
Public Sub performQuack()
    this.QuackBehavior.Quack
End Sub

Public Sub Swim()
    'todo
End Sub
Public Sub Display()
    this.DuckModel.Display
End Sub

'@PredeclaredId
'@Folder("SimUDuck.Models.HeadFirst")
Option Explicit
Private Type TModel
    Display As String
End Type
Private this As TModel
Implements IDuckModel
Private Sub IDuckModel_Display()
    Debug.Print this.Display '"I'm A Mallard Duck"
End Sub

Public Function CreateDuck(ByVal duck As DuckObject) As IDuckModel
    With duck
        Set .FlyBehavior = New FlyWithWingsBehavior
        Set .QuackBehavior = New QuackBehavior
    End With
    With New MallardDuckModel
        .Display = "I'm A Mallard Duck"
        Set CreateDuck = .Self
    End With
End Function
Public Property Get Self() As IDuckModel
    Set Self = Me
End Property
Public Property Get Display() As String
    Display = this.Display
End Property
Public Property Let Display(ByVal value As String)
    this.Display = value
End Property

Public Sub MainDuck()
    Dim duck As DuckObject
    Set duck = New DuckObject
    With New MallardDuckModel
        Dim model As IDuckModel
        Set model = .CreateDuck(duck)
    End With
    With duck
        Set .DuckModel = model
        .performFly
        .performQuack
        .Display
        Dim FlyBehavior As IFlyBehavior
        Set FlyBehavior = New FlyRocketPoweredBehavior
        Set .FlyBehavior = FlyBehavior
        Dim QuackBehavior As IQuackBehavior
        Set QuackBehavior = New SqueakBehavior
        Set .QuackBehavior = QuackBehavior
        .performFly
        .performQuack
        .Display
    End With
    Set duck = New DuckObject
    With New ModelDuckModel
        Set model = .CreateDuck(duck)
    End With
    With duck
        Set .DuckModel = model
        .performFly
        .performQuack
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If it is working then [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is almost certainly a better site to post to though don't expect a translation. You would need to explain what the design pattern should be achieving.

Comment: Thanks QHarr! The design pattern exercise is Strategy, and the VBA code works, but I don't know if it has really implemented the pattern correctly. I can repost to code review. Thank you for your guidance. I am new to SO and how to get help here.

Comment: @QHarr is right, this type of question is *too broad* for SO (it would be ok to ask about any particular specific problem that prevents this code from working as intended though), and a good CR post describes the problem being solved and presents the solution, inviting critiques and enhancements. Welcome to the wonderful compartmentalized world of Stack Exchange, you're embarking on an awesome learning journey with a community that's always going to have your back! Each site on the network has a [ask] and [help/on-topic] page that describes its scope and purpose. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this post when searching for a translation of the Head First Design Patterns exercises.
I’ve been using the RubberduckVBA blog posts as a guide for implementation of OOP concepts and design patterns (specifically Factory) in VBA.

https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/tag/oop/

Comment: Been using RD for about a year now; in the past couple of months I've gone back and revisited Mat's articles. Much of the material had gone way over my head in the beginning; now it is becoming much clearer.